# How to set input value by selecting text from dialog

Tags: react-native

There is an text input view in my app and I want to set it's value after user select some value from a dialog. How do I approach it.

This is my dialog

`addPessageFromDB() {
    var dialog = new DialogAndroid();
    dialog.set(options);
    dialog.show();
  }`

here is options that include

`var options = {
  items: passageList,
  title: 'Sample',
  negativeText: 'Cancel',
  itemsCallback: (id, text) => this.addToInput(text),
};`

now the text i selected from this dialog should insert in this textInput

`<TextInput
          style={styles.inputBox}
          multiline={true}
          value={this.state.text}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})} />`

Comment: What does your code look like? Please update the question to include the salient parts, preferably as close to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as you can come.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set it into the state.text field where you already have wired up the TextInput to read it from. The itemsCallback in dialog should look like this:

itemsCallback: (id, text) => this.setState({ text }),

Comment: I already tried setting state.txt but I don't know why but it didn't work.

Comment: What's that DialogAndroid component? It's not a default one. Are you sure the callback returns text?

Comment: yes, it returns the selected text. I checked it by passing it to Toast.